# Regex that accepts any compilation of any letters any languages,symbols or numbers

Tags: java, regex, subtitle

I'm developing a regex that can fetch text from subtitle file that may be any language and sometimes contains an Unicode characters

```
String str=
   "1
    00:00:25,690 --> 00:00:44,410
    As you can see he is no longer 1 year old, he is 12 years old now.

    2
    00:00:44,410 --> 00:00:58,120
    He helps with the baby girl
";
```

Fetching eaching slot using ragex :

```
((^1\n|(\\n\\d+\n))(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2},\\d{3}.*\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2},\\d{3}))[\\p{P}\\p{L}\\p{P}*-,;'\"\\s]+
```

But found recently that subtitle text slots can contains numbers so how to cover all possibilities of having any character any language any Unicode characters and any number in between.

Tried adding `\p{N}`

But fails. It is now including the timing and subtitle order as well :
sometimes like : `blah blah blah.400:00:44,410`

Is it a way to update regex to match numbers found in the text slot as well but not part of subtitle timing numbers.

Comment: Yes it should be enough. Did you test it?

Comment: Yes but unlikely I will update the question with results

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I have updated the question with status after adding ``\\p{N}``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.srt` [specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip#SubRip_text_file_format) is so simple, you shouldn't write a big, possibly broken RegExp to parse it.

As of Java 8, you can use [`\R`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending) to match any newline.

So split your `.srt` file with `"\\R\\R"` to get subtitle blocks.

For each subtitle block, split around `"\\R"` with a maximum of 3 elements.
You get a `String[]` with :

- id
- t1 --> t2
- text in any language, possibly with newlines and numbers inside.

Done!

```
=> [["1", "00:00:23,480 --> 00:00:27,920", "AM RANDE DER NACHT"],
 ["2", "00:02:22,570 --> 00:02:24,060", "- Salü.\r\n- Monsieur."],
 ["3", "00:02:25,300 --> 00:02:26,890", "- Panne?\r\n- Hm."],
 ["4", "00:02:29,840 --> 00:02:31,830", "Und wieviel brauchst du?"],
 ["5", "00:02:32,340 --> 00:02:34,000", "Von was, Monsieur?"],
 ["6", "00:02:34,120 --> 00:02:35,140", "Na ja, Sprit."],
 ["7", "00:02:36,210 --> 00:02:38,230", "Es äh... es liegt nicht am Sprit."],
 ["8", "00:02:38,490 --> 00:02:40,710", "Es ist, glaub ich, die Kerze."],
 ["9", "00:02:42,220 --> 00:02:43,980", "Was für 'ne Kerze brauchst du?"],
 ["10", "00:02:45,390 --> 00:02:47,800", "Äh, 'ne Kerze eben. Für 'n Moped."]]
```

Comment: Excellent and speedy way thanks so much this is way far better than complex regex

Answer (score 1):

You have one mistake in your character class: the `-` between `*` and `,` means a range and not the char `-`. You can escape it or put it at the beginning/end of the character class.

Fixing this and adding `\p{N}` gives us `[\p{P}\p{L}\p{P}*,;'"\s\p{N}-]+` which is almost perfect but fails because it doesn't include `>`.

`[\p{P}\p{L}\p{P}*,;'"\s\p{N}>-]+` will be perfect, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UX6MQg/1)

Comment: It gets the number but aslo the whole text how make this work for each slot text only

Comment: Just want to fetch text only : "As you can see he is no longer 1 year old, he is 12 years old now."

Comment: BTW I have the timing regex Just need the valid text only part

Comment: Sorry still fetches the whole text , Sorry I had to mention early the regex is applied on a string containing the all subtitle file content

Comment: @YouYou please, edit your question with relevant information :)

Comment: Sorry my mistake thanks for your professional reply question now is updated